# Accented characters missing in ASP Net page

Tags: asp.net, globalization

Despite all attempts and variations to try to display accented characters, I am unable to do so in my ASP Net application.

- I've tried adding it to the web config
- I've saved both the master and default pages as UTF-8

But whatever I do, I can't seem to be able to show the accented chars

My html mark up looks like this
`<h3 class="p5">¿Por qué una “Tercera” Luz de Freno?</h3>`

But I only see
Por qu una Tercera...

It ignores the é and simply does not show it. The page is http://www.suplitekcr.com/motos.aspx in case you want to take a look.

If I view source I can see the é and also Fiddler says "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" which means it is accepting 8859-1 which has the é

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get a 404 when trying to take a look at you page: http://www.suplitekcr.com/motos.aspx

Comment: Also so you see the same behavior in all browsers?

Comment: No problem in seeing the characters on your oage on Firefox, Chrome, IE (Win 7). Did you find out the problem and fix it? Then please post the solution and self-accept it.

Comment: I see it as ¿Por qué una “Tercera” Luz de Freno?

Comment: We all see it correctly... The question is, whether your web browser is (mis)configured... Try a different one.

Answer (score 0):

(@Pal R: the page was temporarily unavailable while I did updates and deployments)

I did find a solution to showing the characters but not to the problem. I bought the template from templatemonster and it had a cufon js library, namely which replaced the current font with a "nicer" one.

It only worked with regular characters but not with nicer ones. The link to the js is down here below:

http://suplitekcr.com/js/cufon-replace.js

I just removed it and lived with the not so nice font.

Any idea on why it does not work with this library? Perhaps the font just does not have those chars?

Answer (score 0):

Cufon is pretty outdated and buggy technology.

It will be much better to switch to WEB Fonts.